# yield from a generator that has return <value> statement in it

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, yield-from

I have a generator with the `return value` statement in it.
If i use next on it I get the Stopiteration: `value` from it as expected.
However when I use `yield from` the `value` is lost.

```
In [1]: def test():
   ...:     return 1
   ...:     yield 2
   ...:

In [2]: t = test()

In [3]: t
Out[3]: <generator object test at 0x000000000468F780>

In [4]: next(t)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-9494367a8bed> in <module>()
----> 1 next(t)

StopIteration: 1

In [5]: def new():
   ...:     yield from test()
   ...:

In [6]: n = new()

In [7]: n
Out[7]: <generator object new at 0x00000000050F23B8>

In [8]: next(n)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-1c47c7af397e> in <module>()
----> 1 next(n)

StopIteration:
```

Is there a way to preserve the `value` when using `yield from` ?
Is this working as intended or maybe it is a bug ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By receiving the value sent by the sub-generator in the `yield from` statement.

Taking a quote from **[PEP 380 -- Syntax for Delegating to a Subgenerator:](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/)**

> The value of the `yield from` expression is the first argument to the `StopIteration` exception raised by the iterator when it terminates.

So with a small tweak, `res` in the `new` generator will contain the value of `StopIteration` raised from the `test` subgenerator:

```
def new():
   res = yield from test()
   return res
```

Now when `next(n)` is executed you'll get the value in the Exception message:

```
n = new()

next(n)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-1c47c7af397e> in <module>()
----> 1 next(n)

StopIteration: 1
```

---

Oh, and as an addendum, you can of course get the 'return' value without it being encapsulated in the `StopIteration` object by using `yield` again:

```
def new():
    res = yield from test()
    yield res
```

Now calling `next(new())` will return the value returned from `test()`:

```
next(new())
Out[20]: 1
```